# Powershell Export-CSV but Change Header Names

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, export-csv

I must be missing something super simple, but due to my inexperience in Powershell, all the resources available are very in depth answers.

I have the following code which is to make a csv file with a directory's filename, modify date and creation date.  It is to exclude certain file paths which are children of this directory.

Here is what I am trying to do:  Upon the output of the csv, change *LastWriteTime* header and *CreationTime* header to a different tag i.e. *Modified Time* or something else.

What must I do to transform this code to modify the headers?  I have seen answers creating arrays and then exporting values, but I feel this is an overly complicated method.  What is the easiest way to accomplish changing the csv headers?

```
Get-ChildItem -path $pathlocation -recurse  |
 where {$_.fullname -notlike $PathsToExclude -and $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} |
  Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime, CreationTime |
  Export-CSV -path $anotherpath -notypeinformation
```

The current csv headers show > "Name","LastWriteTime","CreationTime"

I want the headers to show "File", "Modify Date", "Upload Date"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject)

Comment: use `Select-Object` to select & change the headers you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is using Select-object as expression, for example:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $pathlocation -recurse |
 where {$_.fullname -notlike $PathsToExclude -and $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} |
  Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'File'; Expression = {$_.Name}},@{Name = 'Modify Date'; Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime}},@{Name = 'Upload Date'; Expression = {$_.CreationTime}} |
  Export-CSV -path $anotherpath -notypeinformation
```

For more information [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had some problems using the encapsulated expressions, but with your terminology I now understand where I went wrong.  Much obliged